# Как в TextView установить разный цвет для каждого символа

Tags: android, textview, color, android-textview

Есть к примеру текст "10/5" и как в TextView сделать чтоб к примеру число 10 было зеленым цветом, слэш серым, а число 5 красным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно избежать использования HTML при помощи такого способа:

```
 TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
 Spannable word = new SpannableString("Your message");        

 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 TV.setText(word);
 Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString("Your new message");        

 wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.append(wordTwo);
```

Answer (score 6):

`TextView` поддерживает простейшие теги `HTML`, вроде `<font>`. Использовать можно так:

```
textView.setText(HTML.fromHtml("<font color='#00ff00'>10</font><font color='#555555'>/</font><font color='#ff0000'>5</font>"));
```

Comment: При использовании такого подхода, не забудьте отключить использование юзерскрипта командой     Html.escapeHtml(textView.getText().toString())